Issue launching a local node & instantiating a contract
I'm trying to build a contract and the artifacts are built successfully. However, I keep getting the following error message:
Local node started successfully:
│  portal: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws://localhost:9944/#/explorer
│  logs: tail -f /var/folders/3_/_xrwpqjx25l6ybs5dskbtj7r0000gn/T/.tmptAGZO2
│
■  An error occurred instantiating the contract: Rpc error: RPC error: Error when opening the TCP socket: Connection refused (os error 61)

Any help would be appreciated!
I tried the linked solution but it didn't work

Try that answer. If it doesn't work for you, please update the question, and I'll reopen this.
